# FSO (FileSystemObject) Move folder in itself

Tags: javascript, fso

does anyone know how to recognize the error, when an Folder will be moved in itself?

with the FSO.moveFolder no Problem to move them:

```
fso.MoveFolder("C:\\Temp\\folder1", "C:\\Temp\\folder2\\");
```

but whats happen when i try to move

```
fso.MoveFolder("C:\\Temp\\folder1", "C:\\Temp\\folder1\\");
```

in the console i will get an error, thats OK, but how recognize ist, lets say like the "FolderExists Method "

```
if (fso.FolderExists("C:\\Temp\\myFolder")) {  
    document.write("myFolder exists.");  
}  
else {  
    document.write("myFolder does not exist.");  
}
```

Comment: You could have a try catch and look for an IOException.

Comment: or otherwise you can try to load the source folder, get the path and compare it before moving

Comment: thanks, both solutions are working :)